# Which sentence makes a logical comparison?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

A. In 1990, Chicago had the tallest building of any other city.
B. In 1990, Chicago had the tallest building.
C. In 1990, Chicago had the tallest building of all.
D. In 1990, Chicago had the tallest building in any city.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: They all make a comparison. A is not idiomatic.

Comment: All are ambiguous: (1) In A & D, does "of any (other) city" refer to the USA, the world, ...? (2) In B, the tallest building in that State, in the USA, in the world, ...? (3) In C, "of all" what? - of all the world?

Comment: @TrevorD I'm sorry all choices are pretty ambiguous&mdash;actually they came from my homework questions. I presented the question as-is. I don't know if this site is good for homework questions...

Comment: @user212511 I suggest you acquaint yourself with the following advice about using this site: [Site Tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), & [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  cont'd ... .

Comment: ... cont'd  Additionally (altho' I can't immediately find the respective guidance), it is generally expected that: (a) you do your own research before asking a question AND explain what research you have done and why it doesn't help, especially where answers are likely to be available in standard dictionaries and other reference works; (b) we are NOT here simply to do your homework for you, UNLESS you EXPLAIN your confusion & why you cannot answer the Q. Just getting someone else to give you the correct answer DOES NOT help you to learn why things are right or wrong!

Comment: @user212511 IF you are learning English, you may find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) more suitable.

Comment: @TrevorD thank you so much for the guidance. I didn't include my research because I had no idea about this particular question (all choices are too ambiguous), sorry for that. Next time I'll ask questions in ELL site since there seem to be more similar questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**D.**

A is not correct because Chicago didn't have the building of any other city. (A might be correct if you drop "other.") B is a grammatical statement but not a comparison. C is also grammatical but the comparison isn't as clear. D is grammatical and compares Chicago's building to the buildings in other cities.

Comment: -1 "D is grammatical and compares Chicago's building to the buildings in other cities" ... where? In the whole world? In the USA?

Comment: @TrevorD that's a pretty aggressive downvote my dude. D is the best of the OP's options, and you don't know the context of the sentence. His paragraph could already make clear that he is referring to the US. Or maybe it is the tallest in the world. This is a language site, not a history of the built environment site. Happy holidays.

Comment: You're right: we don't know the context of the sentences, and therefore need to be careful in stating categorically that one is right & the rest are wrong. You are, of course, correct that this is a language site - for that very reason, I think it important to make clear to OP that his sentences are all ambiguous. Additionally, you state that B is "not a comparison" - yet it uses the word "tallest", which is comparative. Without knowing what the previous sentence was, B could be OK: "Cities X, Y & Chicago all have tall buildings. In 1990, Chicago had the tallest building."